# CakePHP MediaView Not Working

Tags: php, cakephp

My site downloads a file from another site then send that file to the client but its not sending it.

```
//Downloads file from veeva to server
public function get_veeva($id = null)
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $asset = $this->Asset->findById($id);
    $vault = $asset['VeevaVault'];

    App::import('Vendor', 'phpVeeva', array('file' => 'veeva' . DS . 'veeva.php'));
    $veeva = new phpVeeva();

    $file = $veeva->getVeevaAsset($vault['veeva_id'], $vault['title']);
    $this->send_veeva($file);
}

//Sends downloaded file to client
public function send_veeva($file)
{
    $filename = $file['filename'];
    $ext = $file['ext'];
    $path = APP . 'tmp/';

    if (file_exists($path . $filename . '.' . $ext)) {
        echo 'Downloading ' . $filename . '.' . $ext . '...';
                //echos /var/www/<sitename>/app/tmp/<filename>.<ext>

        $this->viewClass = 'Media';
        $params = array(
            'id' => sprintf("%s.%s", $filename, $ext),
            'name' => sprintf("%s.%s", $filename, $ext),
            'download' => true,
            'ext' => $ext,
                             'mimeType' => array(
                                   'doc' => 'application/msword',
                                   'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
                                   'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'
                                 ),
            'path' => APP . "tmp" . DS
        );
        $this->set($params);
    }
    else {
        echo $filename . '.' . $ext . ' does not exist at ' . $path;
    }
}
```

The file exists where its supposed to and the page echoes saying its downloading but no download window ever pops up. I've tried with and without the mimeType, same result. My version of Cake doesn't support using Cake response to send files.

**Edit - Added HTTP Headers**

Looking at the headers, the following things pop out:

In the response header, content length is 0 and content type is text/html when I'm trying to send a .doc file so I'm thinking it should be application/msword.

In the request header, the following are accepted, text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml.

Here are the headers:

Response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Thu, 20 Feb 2014 16:32:26 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3

Content-Length: 0

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Request:

GET /assets/get_veeva/530566d7-80c4-4ad7-b815-20600a64cb32 HTTP/1.1

Host: guru-dev.selfip.com

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Referer: http://guru-dev.selfip.com/

Cookie: toolbarDisplay=hide; CAKEPHP=edh8riumsm2kb61ka4dih3v6c1

Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Anybody got any ideas? It looks like its not sending the proper http header.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is your controller. Using `echo` in a controller breaks the MVC-Pattern. In this case PHP sends http headers (content type text/html) to the browser in order to display your "Downloading..." message. These headers can only be sent once. The Browser assumes to deal with text, not with a file.

Remove the `echo` and be sure your view is sending the appropriate headers for your file.